Limit Maximum Time on TimePicker
Now I'm building an app that is capable to update estimated time of order.
And user can limit maximum 50 minute from the current
I'm wondering, is there a way to limit maximum  time on timePicker. especially for time picker for jetpack compose
I expect we can set the limit on timePicker
